# Разместить элементы в таблице равномерно

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать таблицу, где будет выводится некоторая информация, делаю так:

```
    echo "<table style='width: 100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee;'><tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 5%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>№</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Онлайн казино</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Бонус</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Обзоры</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";

echo "<table style='width: 100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee;'><tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 5%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>1</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><img src='style/images/k1.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино Europa</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><span class='ocenka'>1500$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Обзор</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";

echo "<table style='width: 100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee;'><tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 5%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>2</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><img src='style/images/k2.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино Billa</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><span class='ocenka'>1000$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Обзор</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";

 echo "<table style='width: 100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee;'><tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 5%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>3</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><img src='style/images/k3.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино 21 NOVA</td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><span class='ocenka'>950$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td><td style='width: 25%; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>Обзор</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
```

В итоге получается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, в колонке `Онлайн казино` Изображения смещаются)) 
Как сделать чтоб они были расположены ровно на все на одном уровне? 
Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Задайте каждой колонке фиксированную длину. Можно в пикселях, можно в процентах...Например первая колонка "№" может быть `width: 75px;` (достаточно?), а вот вторая - `width: 25%`

Comment: @cyadvert так ведь так-то все и есть

Comment: Погодите, у Вас что, каждая запись - отдельная таблица? Если так, то это надо срочно исправлять - объединять в одну - тогд апроблема решится.

Comment: да, в каждая запись в новой таблице. а как все в одну сделать?

Comment: И еще - иконки казино не смещаются, а центруются...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем вижу несколько.

Первое, и самое главное - нужна одна таблица с 3 рядами, а не три таблицы в один ряд.
Второе, иконки казино не смещаются, а центруются, т.е. у вас `text-align:center;` в `<table>`.

Думаю вот такой вариант Вам больше подойдет:

```
echo "
<table style='width: 100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><tr>
<td style='width: 75px;'>№</td>
<td style='width: 25%;'>Онлайн казино</td>
<td style='width: 25%;'>Бонус</td>
<td>Обзоры</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td style='text-align: left;'><img src='style/images/k1.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино Europa</td>
<td><span class='ocenka'>1500$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td>
<td>Обзор</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td style='text-align: left;'><img src='style/images/k2.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино Billa</td>
<td><span class='ocenka'>1000$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td>
<td>Обзор</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td style='text-align: left;'><img src='style/images/k3.jpg' width='50' height='26' class='imgK' alt='' /> Казино 21 NOVA</td>
<td><span class='ocenka'>950$</span> <span class='gameK'><a href='/'>Играть</a></span></td>
<td>Обзор</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

Все объединено в одну таблицу. Поэтому длины можно проприсать только в заголовке

Ну а вообще - таблица прямо просит хороший CSS :)